# jQuery loop through array and removeClass of 1st two items while giving remaining items a different effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, siblings

I have a list of h2 tags that all have the same class. The dilemma I'm having is I need to remove the classes of the 1st two h2 elements in the list, and then wrap the siblings of the remaining elements in a table. I can only get the code to achieve 1 or the other not both. I have a for loop that starts at 2 to skip over the 1st two elements since their siblings don't belong in a table. The issue with that is skipping over the 1st two now I can't remove their classes because the loop never gets to them. Can someone help me without changing the direction of my code.

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    var togglerHeaders = $("h2.toggler");
    for (i = 2; i < togglerHeaders.length; i++) {
    var currentH2Element = togglerHeaders[i];
    var siblingsofH2 = $(currentH2Element).nextUntil("h2.toggler");
    $(siblingsofH2).wrapAll("<table></table>");
    } // line ends for loop 
    $(".toggler").next().hide();
    $(".toggler").click(function(){
        $(".toggler").next().toggleClass();
    });
}); 
</script>


<h2 class="toggle">
    <span class="myDate">July 2009</span>
</h2>
<div class="wrapInfo">
    <div class="info">
        <p>High School Recent Graduate</p>
    </div>
</div>
<h2 class="toggle">
    <span class="myDate">June 2008</span>
</h2>
<div class="wrapInfo">
    <div class="info">
        <p>High School Senior</p>
    </div>
</div>
<h2 class="toggle">
    <span class="myDate">May 2007</span>
</h2>
<div class="wrapInfo">
    <div class="info">
        <p>High School Junior</p>
    </div>
</div>
<h2 class="toggle">
    <span class="myDate">April 2006</span>
</h2>
<div class="wrapInfo">
    <div class="info">
        <p>High School Sophomore</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about after the for loop you do something like this:
togglerHeaders.slice(0,1).removeClass('toggle');

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. Thank you. I'll try it now.